# What should be the working folder while creating a build agent in TFS 2017?

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, azure-devops, tfsbuild

I created a build agent on the TFS and kept the working folder default i.e. _work. The build fails as it contains no project file. What should be done to use the default working folder?

The Build definition with Visual Studio Build:

[image]

```
2018-02-02T06:02:04.6000428Z ##[section]Starting: Build
2018-02-02T06:02:04.6020618Z Current agent version: '2.122.1'
2018-02-02T06:02:06.5920856Z ##[section]Starting: Initialize Job
2018-02-02T06:02:06.5990706Z Prepare build directory.
2018-02-02T06:02:06.7466794Z Set build variables.
2018-02-02T06:02:06.7501818Z Download all required tasks.
2018-02-02T06:02:06.8317393Z ##[section]Finishing: Initialize Job
2018-02-02T06:02:06.8702795Z ##[section]Starting: Get Sources
2018-02-02T06:02:06.9518235Z Prepending Path environment variable with directory containing 'tf.exe'.
2018-02-02T06:02:06.9523242Z Setting environment variable TFVC_BUILDAGENT_POLICYPATH
2018-02-02T06:02:06.9523242Z Querying workspace information.
2018-02-02T06:02:10.7127112Z ##[command]tf vc workspace /new /location:local /permission:Public ws_2_4 /collection:http://arapl-tfsserver:8080/tfs/RiskAnalytics/ /loginType:OAuth /login:.,******** /noprompt
2018-02-02T06:02:13.6192162Z ##[command]tf vc workfold /unmap /workspace:ws_2_4 $/ /collection:http://arapl-tfsserver:8080/tfs/RiskAnalytics/ /loginType:OAuth /login:.,******** /noprompt
2018-02-02T06:02:15.4369337Z ##[command]tf vc workfold /map /workspace:ws_2_4 $/ARA C:\agent\_work\2\s /collection:http://arapl-tfsserver:8080/tfs/RiskAnalytics/ /loginType:OAuth /login:.,******** /noprompt
2018-02-02T06:02:17.2476000Z ##[command]tf vc workfold /cloak /workspace:ws_2_4 $/ARA/Drops /collection:http://arapl-tfsserver:8080/tfs/RiskAnalytics/ /loginType:OAuth /login:.,******** /noprompt
2018-02-02T06:02:19.2651239Z ##[command]tf vc get /version:1 /recursive /overwrite C:\agent\_work\2\s /loginType:OAuth /login:.,******** /noprompt
2018-02-02T06:02:20.4355458Z All files are up to date.
2018-02-02T06:02:20.4640653Z ##[section]Finishing: Get Sources
2018-02-02T06:02:20.4705702Z ##[section]Starting: Build solution $/ARA/Mainline/CommonBuildProject.proj
2018-02-02T06:02:20.4860808Z ==============================================================================
2018-02-02T06:02:20.4860808Z Task         : MSBuild
2018-02-02T06:02:20.4860808Z Description  : Build with MSBuild
2018-02-02T06:02:20.4860808Z Version      : 1.119.0
2018-02-02T06:02:20.4860808Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2018-02-02T06:02:20.4860808Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613724)
2018-02-02T06:02:20.4860808Z ==============================================================================
2018-02-02T06:02:23.0868381Z ##[command]"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe" "C:\agent\_work\2\s\Mainline\CommonBuildProject.proj" /nologo /nr:false /t:"Clean" /dl:CentralLogger,"C:\agent\_work\_tasks\MSBuild_c6c4c611-aa2e-4a33-b606-5eaba2196824\1.119.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll";"RootDetailId=|SolutionDir=C:\agent\_work\2\s\Mainline"*ForwardingLogger,"C:\agent\_work\_tasks\MSBuild_c6c4c611-aa2e-4a33-b606-5eaba2196824\1.119.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll" /t:build /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform="Any CPU" /p:ReleaseFolder=C:\TFSBuild\Release\ /p:_MSDeployUserAgent="TFS_8fa5b373-d497-4249-be41-399e5ed666ac_build_6_275"
2018-02-02T06:02:23.2459495Z MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.
2018-02-02T06:02:23.2459495Z Switch: C:\agent\_work\2\s\Mainline\CommonBuildProject.proj
2018-02-02T06:02:23.4706080Z ##[error]Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'.
2018-02-02T06:02:23.4776130Z ##[command]"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe" "C:\agent\_work\2\s\Mainline\CommonBuildProject.proj" /nologo /nr:false /dl:CentralLogger,"C:\agent\_work\_tasks\MSBuild_c6c4c611-aa2e-4a33-b606-5eaba2196824\1.119.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll";"RootDetailId=|SolutionDir=C:\agent\_work\2\s\Mainline"*ForwardingLogger,"C:\agent\_work\_tasks\MSBuild_c6c4c611-aa2e-4a33-b606-5eaba2196824\1.119.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll" /t:build /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform="Any CPU" /p:ReleaseFolder=C:\TFSBuild\Release\ /p:_MSDeployUserAgent="TFS_8fa5b373-d497-4249-be41-399e5ed666ac_build_6_275"
2018-02-02T06:02:23.6242159Z MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.
2018-02-02T06:02:23.6247162Z Switch: C:\agent\_work\2\s\Mainline\CommonBuildProject.proj
2018-02-02T06:02:23.6452310Z ##[error]Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'.
2018-02-02T06:02:23.6787543Z ##[section]Finishing: Build solution $/ARA/Mainline/CommonBuildProject.proj
2018-02-02T06:02:23.6852592Z ##[section]Starting: Post Job Cleanup
2018-02-02T06:02:23.6922638Z ##[section]Finishing: Post Job Cleanup
2018-02-02T06:02:23.7012701Z ##[section]Finishing: Build
```

Comment: What specific failure are you getting? Are you using Git or TFVC? If TFVC, is your workspace mapping correct? If Git, are you pointing it to the correct repository?

Comment: Did you get error when you config build agent? Could you share entire build log?

Comment: I am getting the error
"MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist." and so
Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'.

Comment: I am using TFVC and yes I have my workspace mapping correct.

Comment: There is no files downloaded during the get source step? Are you sure that you using the correct repository and your codes are checked in successfully? Can you share a screenshot for your file structure under Code panel?  And did you specify a source version when you queue the build? The logs indicates that it was trying to get version 1 which is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the default working folder path when you config a build agent. When you queue builds, build agent will get sources to the working folder.

The error you got seems you did not map workspace in your build definition. Please check your build definition by going to `Get sources` -- `Workspace mappings` as the screenshot shows, and make sure you have mapped the project you want to build.

[image]

Comment: I changed the workspace map, but still I am getting the error
"MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist."
"Switch: C:\agent\_work\1\s\*.proj "
It seems the agents workspace folder is getting mapped with TFS. What might be the problem?

Comment: Are you able to build your project locally? Have you checked the working folder on build agent machine to see whether all files the build need there?
 How's your build definition like? How did you specify the solution in the build task?

Comment: Yes, I am able to build my project locally, my working folder is the default working folder which is _work and I am unaware of what the folder should be.I have created 2 build definitions (a)With the MSBuild tool (b)With Visual Studio Build. The problem is that I cant seem to work around with the default working directory of the agent(_work)

Comment: Could you share your entire build log in your original post?

Comment: The build log has been added

Comment: First, go to build agent machine, and check whether the .proj file under `C:\agent\_work\2\s\Mainline`. Then, try to select the project by clicking `...` in your build task, the format should like `$/ARA/Mainline/CommonBuildProject.proj`, not `$\ARA\Mainline\CommonBuildProject.proj`.

Comment: C:\agent\_work\2\s is empty, but when I copy the build folder in the _work\2\s it deletes everything and nothing happens after.

Comment: What's the meaning of "copy the build folder"? Did you select the server path by clicking `...` in Workspace mappings?

Comment: "copy the build folder" the folder which I want to build i.e. the Mainline folder and yes i selected the server path

Comment: I think you set `Clean` to `true` in `Get sources`. If you run [Get command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/get-command) on your build agent machine, will it download the sources?